# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() gives memory warning!

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() in -drawRect: of a UIView inherited class. Then view is added on an scrollView. In -scrollViewDidEndZooming: withView: atScale: I am initiating the view's -setNeedsDisplay.
So calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() gives memory warning.

Please anyone help me in fixing this.

Comment: There's more than one memory warning that will surface itself to an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

didReceiveMemoryWarning is not related to a single function call.It's called when your application uses too much memory often as a result of leaking memory.